# How to use fixtures and capturing of the stdout in pytest at the same time?

Tags: python, pytest

How do I have something like this:

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [
    ("3+5", 8),
    ("2+4", 6),
    ("6*9", 42),
])
def test_printed_out_value(test_input, expected, capsys): # <-- notice the third argument
    print test_input
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out == expected
```

Above code fails because the global fixture capsys can't be used when we use parameterization. By that I mean I can't find a way to pass it inside the function. Is there way I'm not seeing where I can [capture the output](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html#default-stdout-stderr-stdin-capturing-behaviour) but still use [parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understood your question correctly, but the following code snipped works (2 tests pass, 1 fails):

```
import pytest

class __capsys_class__:
    def readouterr(self, in_str):
        return eval(in_str), None

@pytest.fixture(scope = 'module')
def capsys():
    return __capsys_class__()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('in_param', [
    ('3+5', 8),
    ('2+4', 6),
    ('6*9', 42),
    ])
def test_printed_out_value(capsys, in_param):
    test_input, expected = in_param
    print(test_input) # Python 3 print function!
    out, err = capsys.readouterr(test_input)
    assert out == expected
```

First, I always put fixtures at the beginning of the 'list' of arguments. Seems to work this way. Second, I just send your tuples into the test as they are (`in_param`) and unpack them inside the test.

EDIT: `stdout` is captured and displayed when a test fails. For the above code, it looks like this:

```
~> pytest 
========================================================== test session starts ===========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.2, pytest-3.3.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/ernst/Desktop/so/tests, inifile:
collected 3 items                                                                                                                        

test_demo.py ..F                                                                                                                   [100%]

================================================================ FAILURES ================================================================
___________________________________________________ test_printed_out_value[in_param2] ____________________________________________________

capsys = <test_demo.__capsys_class__ object at 0x7fd57e60c860>, in_param = ('6*9', 42)

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('in_param', [
        ('3+5', 8),
        ('2+4', 6),
        ('6*9', 42),
        ])
    def test_printed_out_value(capsys, in_param):
        test_input, expected = in_param
        print(test_input)
        out, err = capsys.readouterr(test_input)
>       assert out == expected
E    assert 54 == 42

test_demo.py:21: AssertionError
---------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------------------------
6*9
=================================================== 1 failed, 2 passed in 0.03 seconds ===================================================
```

Check the `6*9` in the second-to-last line. This was printed by the print function in the test.